# How set auto scrolling horizontally of com.yarolegovich.discretescrollview.DiscreteScrollView

Tags: android

in app/build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.4.9'
```

in my snippet:

```
private void initSlider() {
        List<String> serviceUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
        serviceUrls.add("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/44444?s=48x48&d=identicon");
        serviceUrls.add("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/33333?s=48x48&d=identicon");
        serviceUrls.add("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/11111?s=48x48&d=identicon");
        serviceUrls.add("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/22222?s=48x48&d=identicon");
        DiscreteScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.picker);
        InfiniteScrollAdapter wrapper = InfiniteScrollAdapter.wrap(new AgentServiceAdapter(serviceUrls));
        scrollView.setAdapter(wrapper);
        scrollView.setSlideOnFling(true);
    }
```

in xml

```
<com.yarolegovich.discretescrollview.DiscreteScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/picker"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:dsv_orientation="horizontal" />
```

as result it show images and I by swipe scroll them horizontally. 
Nice. It's work.
But I need to when show scrooView to AUTOMATE start scrolling horizonatally.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule calls to `scrollView.smoothScrollToPosition(positon)` yourself by using a handler with a timer.

```
int NUM_TOTAL_ITEMS = itemList.size(); // you can use itemView.getPosition()
int position = 0;
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    if (position == NUM_TOTAL_ITEMS - 1) {
        position = 0;
    }
    scrollView.smoothScrollToPosition(positon);
    position++;
   }
};
```

Comment: I found simpler solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
private DiscreteScrollView discreteScrollView;
    private Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable timerRunnable;

    timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    discreteScrollView.smoothScrollBy(5, 0); // 5 is how many pixels you want it to scroll horizontally by
                    timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 10); // 10 is how many milliseconds you want this thread to run
                }
            };
            timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some modifications in a_subscriber answer. His solution is continuously moving and I added for 1 item move then stop then move. You can change as your requirement.

```
var delay = 100L

val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
activity!!.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
val height: Int = displayMetrics.heightPixels
var width= displayMetrics.widthPixels
var pixelPersentage= (width*0.05).roundToInt()
width -= pixelPersentage * 4
var pixel=pixelPersentage

try {
        timerRunnable = object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                try {
                    if(pixel>width){
                        delay=3000
                        pixel=widthPers
                    }
                    else {
                        pixel += widthPers
                        delay=100
                    }
                    sliderLayout.smoothScrollBy(
                        pixelPersentage,
                        0
                    ) 
                    timerHandler.postDelayed(
                        this,
                        delay
                    ) 
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                }
            }
        }
        timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 3000)
  } catch (e: Exception) {

  }
```